# sharepoint 2010 infopath autopopulate people picker field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I have a problem when I try to autopopulate a people picker filed in infopath 2010 in a sharepoint 2010 form.

I am changing the edit form. In the edit form I want to autopopulate a people picker field (wich is based on a people column of the connected list) based upon another people picker field in the same list. In easy words I want to copy/past a value from one people picker field to another (in the edit form).

This does not work within the edit form. But it works in the new form. Has there anyone an idea for that.

I am not allowed to use coded solutions, only configuration (rules).

Thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the 3 attributes/values of one people picker to another.

These are:

- DisplayName
- AccountId
- AccountType

Now you can put a rule that when 1st people picker changes value, it will pass the 3 attributes to the 2nd people picker.

Comment: yes i know. but this does work for the new form but it does not work for the edit form. In the edit form the field stays empty ...